# how can I define functions in haskell using uppercase letters?

Tags: function, haskell

For example, how can I define a function to generate fibonacci numbers using uppercase letters like this: FIB n
I need to call the function from the terminal using only uppercase letters like this: FIB 7

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. Take a look at the linked question, which asked about the same thing, for some more details and strategies to get around this restriction.

Answer (score 3):

[You can't](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#ids).  Functions in Haskell must start with lowercase unicode characters or an underscore.  Symbols beginning with an upper case letter are reserved for types and constructors.

Why do you need to call the function from the terminal using only upper case letters?  That seems like a rather arbitrary constraint.

---

If you really really wanted to read STDIN and process that, I would suggest writing something like this

```
import System.IO
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Control.Monad (forever)

data Operation
    = FIB Integer
    | FAC Integer
    | ADD Integer Integer
    deriving (Read)
-- The read instance is important here

fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

eval :: Operation -> Integer
eval (FIB n) = fib n
eval (FAC n) = product [1..n]
eval (ADD a b) = a + b

repl :: IO ()
repl = forever loop
    where
        parseResponse :: String -> String
        parseResponse resp = case readMaybe resp of
            Just op -> show $ eval op
            Nothing -> "Invalid operation"
        loop = do
            putStr "> "
            resp <- getLine
            putStrLn $ parseResponse resp

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    repl
```

This allows the user to type in the *exact* name of the data constructor, then you interpret that data constructor (yes, this is the entire code for a very simple interactive scripting language that can only do fibs, factorials, and addition) into a result.  If an invalid operation was typed in, it will respond with `Invalid operation`.  You can quit the interpreter only with <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>.

Comment: It is for a class. Anyway, do you think the only way to achieve this would be through taking a string input and processing it to call the required function?

Comment: @Reeshabh In this case, yes.  If you were going to be writing some sort of [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) for your class, you would have to do this parsing anyway.  If you just wanted to do it in GHCi then you would have to use an identifier starting with a lower case letter.  I'll edit my answer to show a few examples of what you could do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. Function and variable names has to start with small letters. First capital letter is reserved for type constructors:
[Haskell specs](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#ids)

Comment: Not just type constructors; constructors in general, and also classes.