# data constructor not in the scope Haskell ？

Tags: haskell, constructor, scope, datalist

here are the concerning data definition

```
data Decl = Decl Name Type

data FunDecl = FunDecl Type Name [Decl] [Decl] Cmd

newtype Program = Program [FunDecl]
```

what i wanna do is to filter the [FunDecl] with the name of "main"

```
filterByname :: Program -> Program
filterByname (Program p) =
  let p_main = filter (\FunDecl Type name [Decl] [Decl] cmd -> Name == "main") in Program $ p_main p
```

but i get the error message of "Not in scope: data constructor ‘Type’"
how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be confusing types/type constructors with variable names. `[Decl]` is a type, and `Decl` is both a type constructor and a type (`data Decl = Decl ...`), so neither are valid variable names - you want to assign an identifier to the value you'll be passed (which is of type `[Decl]`) so you need to use an identifier like `decl1` for it (may be worth looking over [this tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions)).

Words beginning with an uppercase letter can only be types and type constructors - only words beginning with lowercase (and that aren't restricted) can be identifiers ([see this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938802/how-can-i-define-functions-in-haskell-using-uppercase-letters) or the [grammar specification](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#ids)).

---

So you need to change your lambda:

```
\(FunDecl declType name decl1 decl2 cmd) -> name == "main"
```

The `FunDecl` stays, as it's a type constructor that we're pattern matching against, where the identifiers given to the matched parts are called `name`, `decl1` etc.

`Name` is also changed to `name` in the lambda body so that we refer to the argument, not to the type constructor `Name`.

---

Given that you're only using the `name` argument, you can also define your lambda as:

```
\(FunDecl _ name _ _ _) -> name == "main"
```

Where `_` is a "special" identifier which means "an argument that we don't want to give a name". This is usually better practice.

Comment: thanks a lot! I have been thinking this question for several hours.. as a new learner of haskell

Comment: but i got a another error : The constructor ‘FunDecl’ should have 5 arguments, but has been given none when i followed your instruction

Comment: @ZheYuHe Oh yeah, my bad - you need to use brackets to group the data constructor so that your lambda takes one argument, not 6 individual ones. See my edit.

Comment: yesterday, i tried " \FunDecl (declType name decl1 decl2 cmd) -> name" to make it meet the requirement but failed... now i finally understand this kind of syntax after seeing you edit. Thank you!!